# making the A links search for any link on a page

Tags: sharepoint-2013, modalpopup

Is it possible to have a generic clickhandler code placed in a general location that can be called upon by any page for cases to open a video in a modal pop-up?  The links need to be set up by the content owners in SharePoint 2013.